# How to encrypt using SHA256 and salt?

Tags: php, cryptography, salt, sha256, saltedhash

Before: I'm sorry for my english.

Ok right now i'm using the following encrypt method:

SHA256_PassHash(inputtext, "78sdjs86d2h", MyHash, sizeof(MyHash));

SHA256 WITH SALT: "78sdjs86d2h

Right now i'm checking the password like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $check = get_row("SELECT playerID FROM playeraccounts WHERE playerName='$username' && playerPassword='$password'");
    if(isset($check['playerID']))
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
        mysql_query("UPDATE playeraccounts SET rpgon=1 WHERE playerName='$username'");
        $id = $check['playerID'];
        header("location: index.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $err = 'Username sau parola incorecte';
    }
}
```

How can i make it work with this salt method ? Please i'm not very bright about PHP ... can somebody enlight me about how to encrypt the input text ?

Comment: You should not handle username / password in your app or PHP code directly. Rather an authentication framework should have done that for you.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/PHPAuth/PHPAuth for instance

Comment: SHA256 is a hash function. You don't use it for encryption.

Comment: MySQL functions are depreciated you may wish to start MySQLi or pdo

Comment: Yeah that is a good point too... SHA256 is a cryptographic hash function... More on this here http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80623/hashing-vs-one-way-encryption

Comment: SHA*, MD5, etc are not encryption, they are cryptographic hash codes which are one-way functions, that is there is no way to un-scramble them back to the original.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use SHA256 (which for future reference [is a hash function, not an encryption method](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded)) for storing passwords. Refer to *[How to safely store your users' passwords](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#php)* for up-to-date best practices.

Since you're asking about PHP, you want to use [`password_hash()`](https://secure.php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify()`](https://secure.php.net/password_verify).

Also, [beware of SQL injection corner cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/2224584).